# Copy text from text box onkeyinput to other textbox based on dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Good day.

I need to copy what's being typed into a textbox to multiple other text boxes.

The catch is that there is a dropdown which must determine this.

The process: User will enter a "Commodity" into the "Commodity" text box.

After this, they will then select from a dropdown the number of "Delivery Places". If they choose "1"; textbox "Commodity1" will have the same contents as the main "Commodity" textbox.

If they choose "2" as "DeliveryPlaces", both "Commodity1" & "Commodity2" will have the contents typed into "Commodity". This process should follow until "5" for "DeliveryPlaces".

The reason I want it done like this is that most of our clients will only order one type of commodity, even though it will be transported to multiple locations;

```js
function copy(){
if (document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value = "1")
  {
    document.getElementById("Commodity1").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;

  }
  
 else if (document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value = "2")
  {
    document.getElementById("Commodity1").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity2").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;

  }
  
  else if (document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value = "3")
  {
    document.getElementById("Commodity1").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity2").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity3").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;

  }
  
  else if (document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value = "4")
  {
    document.getElementById("Commodity1").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity2").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity3").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity4").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;

  }
  
  else if (document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value = "5")
  {
    document.getElementById("Commodity1").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity2").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity3").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity4").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
 document.getElementById("Commodity5").value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;

  }
  
else 
  {
      document.getElementById("Commodity1").value="";
   document.getElementById("Commodity2").value="";
   document.getElementById("Commodity3").value="";
   document.getElementById("Commodity4").value="";
   document.getElementById("Commodity5").value="";

  }
}
```

```html
<p>
Commodity
</p><input type="textbox" id="Commodity" onkeyinput="copy();">
<p>
Commodity1
</p><input type="textbox" id="Commodity1"> 
<p>
Commodity2
</p><input type="textbox" id="Commodity2">
<p>
Commodity3
</p><input type="textbox" id="Commodity3">
<p>
Commodity4
</p><input type="textbox" id="Commodity4">
<p>
Commodity5
</p><input type="textbox" id="Commodity5">

<p>
Delivery Places
</p>
<select style="width:50px;" id="DeliveryPlaces">
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

so by filling it in automatically we save the user some time.

I managed to get it working **without** the *if* conditions, that was simple enough. Now, however, it's only filling in "Commodity1" even though I choose a "DeliveryPlace" which IS NOT "1".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch:

`if (document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value = "1")`

to 
    `if (document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value == "1")`

The code is actually switching DeliveryPlaces to 1 in your statement

Comment: This solved it thanks a lot dude. I just added the extra "=" and made this onchange event for  "DeliveryPlaces": onchange="copy(Commodity1);copy(Commodity2);copy(Commodity3);copy(Commodity4);copy(Commodity5);"                                                                                   

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
var e = document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces")
var selection = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Then do your condition based on the value in selection.

you are currently selecting the value of the Select element not the option you have actually selected.

Edit: it may be text rather than value you need on your selection, but give it a go!

Comment: Thank you will try in a bit and let you know.

Comment: How would I implement that? "document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").options[e.selectedIndex].value=1;?"

Comment: I've changed the code slightly, to make it easier to read (and also be correct!). place that above all if statements then replace document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces").value with selection in all your if statements.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```
function copy() {
    var e = document.getElementById("DeliveryPlaces")
    var selection = parseInt(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);
    var input = document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
    var field;

    for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        field = "Commodity" + i;
        if (i <= selection) {
            document.getElementById(field).value = input;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(field).value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can clear the other commodities, when you change to a lower delivery place + you can easily add more by editing the for loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am still new so this loop really taught me an easier way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

Your function should receive the number of the dropdown. That is, if you selected 2 copy (2) so you can use a for and go through the ones you want to fill

```
for (i = item.length; i = 0; i--) { 
    document.getElementById("Commodity"+i).value=document.getElementById("Commodity").value;
}
```

The for will go from low to high until it reaches 0. that means that it will count if it is 5. 5,4,3,2,1 and will fill all the fields that you want. This avoids the amount of spaghetti code you have in your structure.

I understand that you are using pure javascript. But you could use jquery and it would make the job easier.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thanks for the loop! Will be saving for future reference. I am starting to understand the loops more now with all these insightful answers. I appreciate your help. The issue is solved :)

Comment: At the friend's order please vote for my answer and mark it as the correct one if possible. Any doubt we are in order